# Как сделать свой QTableView, чтобы ячейки в строке выводить в несколько рядов

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

Имеется ввиду как сделать так, чтобы QTableView выводил в несколько рядов каждую строку.
Как бы по некоторому шаблон, например так:

```
1 1 3 5 8
0 2 3 4 4
```

где цифры это номера колонок модели данных QSqlTableModel например.
Видно, что парные цифры это как-бы общая область для одной ячейки (например 4 4).
Или ещё хороший пример как в 1С, где одна ячейка может быть под другой.

Comment: Вопрос как я понял пока - не решается штатными классами Qt. Тут похоже надо велосипедить.